# ORA-28365: wallet is not open error

Tags: java, database, oracle

Getting below error on production environment. Never got in on local box. After reading [Opening the Encrypted Wallet](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11159_01/books/install/eBilling_Install_DatabaseOra11.html)
i understand Wallet must be open before opening the database.

But weird thing this errror is thrown for specific transaction rarely. Why so ? If wallet would not have opened it would have been issue for all transactions. Correct or
some specific wallet got attached with some specific data. If yes,Is there a way to identify that ?

`ORA-28365: wallet is not open error`